# How to open the MakeHuman Plugin Tab?

Tags: makehuman

I want to import a MakeHuman figure for scale.

I have installed the [MakeHuman plug-in](https://github.com/makehumancommunity/makehuman-plugin-for-blender) for Blender and it is showing as enabled in the add-ons list. I have enabled Accept Connections in the Community -> Socket tab in MakeHuman.

**How do I open the window/tab in Blender in order to use the plugin?**

I have googled for how to show add-on tabs and add-on windows in Blender, but have not found any general instructions. I have looked in the File -> Import menu, the Modelling Object Mode Add menu, the scene tree dialog context menu, and the add workspace menu, but it cannot find any reference to it.

Comment: Try pressing N in the 3d viewport - a box will appear in the top right corner with tabs with vertically rotated text on the right side of it (Item, Tool, View, etc...) See if the MakeHuman addon has left a tab there.

Comment: Hi @ChristopherBennett, I have made sure that the viewport is in focus and pressed N, but do not see anything change in the GUI. I am in the modelling edit mode view at the moment, if that makes a difference. I have the Industry Compatible bindings on as well.

Comment: Strange, pressing N in almost any viewport should bring up a toolbar from the right, both in object and edit mode (also sclupt, vertex paint, draw, etc...). If you cannot bring up this toolbar (by pressing N when the mouse is in the viewport, by default) then I would look into why this is happening because often add-ons (I'm thinking of ones such as FaceBuilder) place their controls in this menu.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett thank you, that got me on the right track. I couldn't make the shortcuts work but I found a teeny arrow that showed the tabs and MH was there (I highlighted it in an image below).

Answer (score 1):

The MakeHuman tab is in the viewport list as @ChristopherBennett says.

For my instance of 2.83.4 the key shortcuts did not work, but the list can be opened by clicking the little arrow near the top right of the viewport (shown below).

[image: Arrow to open the tabs list]